# PHP For Loop Printing An Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

This might seem like a really easy question but it has got me stumped lol. I am trying to print the rows received from the database. I want to store the rows inside an array and then print them using a for loop. I know that the query works however when I try to print the array elements it only prints the word array. I have tired doing it with a foreach loop and a simple for loop. If anyone can point me in the right direction would be a life saver.

**Printing Php Code**

```
<?php

    $type = "FREE";
    $free = getTerms($type);
    echo "<p>";
    for($j = 0; $j < count($free); $j++)
    {
    echo "start".$free[$j]."end";
    }
    echo "</p>";                        
?>
```

**geting the rows from the database**

```
function getTerms($type)
{
    $terms = array();
    $connection = mysql_open(); 
    $query = "select terms from terms_and_con where accountType='$type' && currentTerms='YES'";
    $results = mysql_query($query, $connection) or show_error("signUp.php", "", "");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
    {
       $terms[] = $row;
    }
    mysql_close($connection) or show_error("signUp.php", "", "");
    return $terms;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Each entry in the `$free` array is itself an array (from `$row`).

Try

```
echo 'start', $free[$j]['terms'], 'end';
```

Alternatively, you may find a `foreach` loop more semantically appropriate

```
foreach ($free as $row) {
    echo 'start', $row['terms'], 'end';
}
```

*Edit:* I'd advise using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysql_fetch_array()` if you're only going to use associative entries from `$row`.

Comment: +1 to note, just because you only select one value from MySQL doesn't mean it returns just that element, it's still a key=>value pair in an array.

Comment: +1 i thought he wanted to print the array, just the terms value from the query.

Answer (score 1):

the thing is function mysql_fetch_array ( as the name suggests) returns an ( in your case both associative and number) array. so $row is actually array(0 => *VALUE*, 'terms' => '*VALUE*')

So what you are trying to echo is actually an array.

Simple fix:
replace:

```
$terms[] = $row;
```

with:

```
$terms[] = $row[0];
```